# WCF Rest With Jquery Ajax and .Net Application consultation

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, rest, cross-domain

I need your help and consultation in a problem that i have faced based on some wrong architecture application design.

The case: im working in web application built on asp.NET 4.0 to a client and im almost have done 85% out of this project, the project architecture as the following:

- Front End Server: Web Application, Ajax JQuery Calling WCF Rest Service.
- Application Server: Host the WCF Rest Service and the DAL components.
- SQL Server: host the database it self

My problem i think is with the CROSS-DOMAIN issue, and my client ensure that the solution should be deployed on  the 3 servers, as u know i have already stucked with solution and i need to find an exit to my problem. all the 3 servers are hosted at the same DOMAIN but with different ip address, i tried to go with JSONP approach but it seems have some limitations and drawbacks such as no error handling which is one my client requirement (is it possible to make POST, PUT operations using JSONP ?), also i tried to maintain the server response headers but i think its not going to work with all browsers such as IE 9, Chrome ..

This problem really puts me in a very embarrassing situation and i need your professional and consultation help, some people suggested that i create another WCF rest hosted in the frontend and it calls the other service but i think it will make the performance very slow.

Cheers.

Comment: But what exactly the problem. If all computer placed at the same domain.

Comment: But I had the same setup and it's working ok. Where exactly the problem ? Between client and server ? Between server and database ?

Comment: @Gregory Nozik Between client and server, when placing the rest host in the client server it works like charm, if i move the rest to the app server and point the ajax to call it from there it returns Status:0 error message: "error"

Comment: I had the same problem . Did you try to debug the rest service. May be the problem  with the installation.WCF Rest 4 have problems to work with IIS 6. If you invoke the rest service from app server locally will it work ?

Comment: its IIS7 Windows 2008 on all machines

Comment: If you invoke locally in app server the rest service . It's working ?

Comment: you mean to move the client app into the app server and try ?, i have tried to call the rest from fiddler and it was working, btw i disabled all the authentication except for anonymous access

Comment: Do you have viber installed . What is your email ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been battling this issue too, and have not found a perfect answer yet.  Here are some things that will at least get you further down the road.

One option is to configure your webHttp behavior so that it doesn't include the faultExceptionEnabled="true" attribute.  This way, jQuery won't hit the error handler, but the success handler.  The WebFaultException should still populate the data parameter in the success handler with JSON.  The drawback to this approach is that I haven't found a way to wrap the fault exception so I can easily check if an error actually occurred in that success handler.  All I get in the JSON are the properties of the fault.

The next option is just to drop the web front end into a different virtual directory on the same web site as the WCF service.  There shouldn't be any cross-domain issues with this approach.  Not always an ideal solution, but it works.

I had issues locally as well if I use the Cassini web server or IIS Express.  I think the browser interprets requests to web sites on different ports as a cross-domain request.  The only way I could work locally with any success is if I installed IIS on my dev box and hosted both the service and the front end on the default web site.

If anybody has figured out a better way, please share.  It's enough to drive a guy bonkers.